# Space displays strangely in VSCode, how to fix it?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1e7P.png)

I'm using VSCode in version 1.36, the space displays in it looks so strange, the width of 4 space equals to 2 characters. I don't know whether it's a feature in this new version or a bug,  since I couldn't find the setting of recovering it to normal. How to set the space equal to one character in this version or it's exactly a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I've found what the problem is. Resetting the `"editor.fontFamily": "monospace"`. See this issue
[reference](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/77612).